# Translation of "What type of an animal are you interested in?"

Tags: verb, preposition

How would one go about translating the sentence: "What type of animal are you interested in?" I read that "to be interested in" is "sich interessieren für".

Would it be: "Was für ein Tier interessieren Sie sich für?"

Or does the *für* from "Was für" make it so one doesn't need the second *für*?

That would make it: "Was für ein Tier interessieren Sie sich?"

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation could be:

"Was für eine Tierart interessiert sie?"

I'm native German, but my grammar knowledge is bad, hence I'm bad in arguing why I did choose this solution. You don't need the second für. But you have to amend interessieren to interessiert. See the -> [Duden website entry](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/interessieren) for all the cases. In this sentence you talk directly to another person, he's alone, so Singular/Indikativ -> Sie interessiert.

Ad-hoc I would translate it to:

"Für welche Tierart interessieren Sie sich?"

Sounds nicer.

Comment: "Tierart" is ''species''. ''type of animal'' is a looser, unscientific term; it should become ''Welche Art Tier...''
(Sorry, chronic pedant here.)

Comment: Good argument :) But the sentence does not sound as good as before. "Welche Art Tier interessiert sie?" Maybe it would make more sense when using Tier generally. "Welche Tiere interessieren dich?"

Comment: An exact answer would be indeed **Für was für Tiere interessieren Sie sich?** It's completely correct, compare: **Über was für Dinge ärgerst du dich am meisten?**